# jquery fancybox: implement "after" photo

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am making a gallery for an architecture firm and I want to use fancybox. A requirement for the gallery is that certain images have associated "after" images. The image relations are similar to this:

[image]

There does not seem like there is any easy way to do this with the api functions. My approach thus far has been

Skip "after" photos by assigning them the class "skip"

```
$('a:not(.skip)').fancybox();
```

Certain imageas have data elements that tip off the existence of an "after" image and i add a link in the gallery view if that's the case...

```
afterLoad   : function() {
    if(this.element.context.dataset.before==1){
        this.skin.prepend( '<div onclick="javascript:parent.$.fancybox(afterimg);" style="margin-left:50%">Before Image</div>' );
        }

    }
```

In order to get this approach to work I have to close fancybox and re-open, and then to get back into the normal gallery I have to close and reopen again.

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to do? not showing the after images in the fancybox gallery?  ... if so, just remove the `rel` attribute from those after images rather than adding them a `skip` *class*, otherwise please elaborate. Also, it would be a good idea to see the relevant part of your html

Comment: I can change the html to anything to accomplish this goal: what I want to do is make a way to navigate through a gallery structured like in the diagram i attached, while fancybox is open

Comment: Just to clarify : From "*img 1*" you move to "*img 1 after*" and then "*img 2*" ... from "*img 4*" to "*img 4 after*" then "*img 5*"? assuming that "*img 1 after*" and  "*img 4 after*" are not in the html, is that correct? ... also, I asked you to post your html to check if what I am guessing is correct AND to know what do you use to know if there is an "after image" (I hate guessing and spend hours asking questions back and forth ... help me to help you ;)